# How to use response.follow() with a callback to get a specific value? Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a spider in Scrapy and I modularized it as much as possible (perhaps too much).

I have a function that crawls through an author's page such as [this one](https://www.spiegel.de/impressum/autor-55fbc54a-0001-0003-0000-000000025831) and yields author's information:

```py
def get_authors(self, response) -> Author:
        """Crawls through an author's page and yields author's information.
        """
        print('get_authors:')

        # Create a proto object.
        author = Author()
        author.id = '0' # CHANGE LIKE IN THE EXTRACTORS
        author.url = response.url
        author.name = str(self.get_author_name(response))
        author.topics = str(self.get_author_description(response))
        author.date_last = str(self.get_author_last_article_datetime(response)) # NOT WORKING
        ...
```

The date is easier to extract from an article's own page and I already have a function for that. My problem is that **the function needs to be ran on a different response.**

The only way I have found to call a function on a different response is by doing `response.follow(...)` or `scrapy.Request(url, callback=func)`. The problem is that both of them don't return what I need. **They return a request.**

Here is the problematic part:

```py
    def get_author_last_article_datetime(self, response):
        """Returns an author's latest article's date of publishing.

        Args:
            response:
                A response object of an author's page.

        Returns:
            A string containing the author's last article's pulishing date.

        Raises:
            Exception: An error occured while retrieving the author's last article url.
        """
        try:
            article_url = response.xpath('//div[@data-area="article_teaser>news-m-wide" and @data-pos="1:1"]//h2/a/@href').get()
            return str(response.follow(article_url, callback = self.get_article_datetime))
        except Exception:
            print("An error occured while retrieving the author's last article date.")
            last_date = 'N/A'
            return last_date
```

Function `get_article_datetime()` *returns* a time object when given an article's page.

**When I run `get_authors` instead of the scraped date, I get a GET request in its place.**

**How can I return what I want?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `Author` details (everything except *last_article_date*) and next `yield` `last_article_url` and **pass as cb_kwargs** your `Author` object:

```
   def parse_author(self, response): 
    author = Author()
    author.id = '0' # CHANGE LIKE IN THE EXTRACTORS
    author.url = response.url
    author.name = str(self.get_author_name(response))
    author.topics = str(self.get_author_description(response))
    last_article_url = response.xpath('//div[@data-area="article_teaser>news-m-wide" and @data-pos="1:1"]//h2/a/@href').get()
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=response.urljoin(last_article_url),
        cb_kwargs={
            'author': author,
        },
        callback=self.parse_last_article_date,
    )

   def parse_last_article_date(self, response, author):
      author.date_last = response.xpath('//some/xpath/here').get()
      yield author
```

Comment: What is the difference between `url = last_article_url` and `url=response.urljoin(last_article_url)`?

Moreover, suppose I want to also find the author's first ever article's publishing date, would I have to call that function from `parse_last_article_date`? If yes, I would end up with a chain of methods...
(unfortunately the first article is also not on the same page as the last article, which means that I would have yet another request to make)

Comment: If your `last_article_url` is a relative URL then `response.urljoin()` make it absolute (you can use `.follow()` for that)